# How allow end user to create validation rules using regex?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

In my application i am allowing users to create some validation rules using charterers `'*'`, `'?'` where `'*'` means many charterers and `'?'` means one character, For example user can write `"*Ma?s*"` so it should match something like this `"ajdg adbf MaKs sjklfd"` sorry for the example but i have nothing in mind and maybe the user input more complex rules.

I Solved the problem by sending the rule and the match string to SQL Server database and replaced each `'*'` with `'%'` and each `'?'` with `'_'` and used like condition and works great, but there is a lot of validation rules the user can enter and a lot of matches so there is a lot of db operations so i thought i night use the new c++ 11 regex to do that in client side, and i searched a lot and read a lot of articles but no answer.

So can this be done in regex ? and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a regular expression, you just need to convert your specifications to a regex. For that, just replace:

- `*` by `.*` (or `.+`, depending if you want at least one character or not)
- `?` by `.`

**Note:**

`.` matches *any character*. If you're looking for letters only, you can use replace `.` by `[a-zA-Z]`. For numbers, `\d`. For letters and numbers, `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, etc.

Comment: Thank you it worked, i didn't try it until today 
but now i must not let the user enter special characters are used by regex right ?

Comment: You have two options: 1) do not allow it, or 2) escape the characters. I don't know how to do it in C++, but in C# you do `Regex.Escape("*")` and it will return `\*`. If you find a way of escaping characters in C++, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by replacing `*` with `.*` and `?` by `.`. Note however, that most C++ `<regex>` implementations I came across are not really functional, so for the time being you would need to rely on [`Boost.regex`](http://boost.org/libs/regex).

As an aside, note that you would need to sanitize the user input first. Otherwise a malicious user can do very bad things to your system.

Comment: Thanks you, your solution worked but i cant accept two answers so i accepted the oldest one